# Need to Extract all data based on condition in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, extract, json-path-expression, json-extract

I got below json as response from HttpRequest of jmeter.

```
[
    {
        "state": {
            "data": {
                "linearId": {
                    "externalId": null,
                    "id": "1234"
                },
                "Contract": {
                    "Status": {
                        "displayName": "Accepted"
                    },
                    "contractType": "life"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "state": {
            "data": {
                "linearId": {
                    "externalId": null,
                    "id": "4567"
                },
                "Contract": {
                    "Status": {
                        "displayName": "Rejected"
                    },
                    "contractType": "life"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "state": {
            "data": {
                "linearId": {
                    "externalId": null,
                    "id": "7890"
                },
                "Contract": {
                    "Status": {
                        "displayName": "Accepted"
                    },
                    "contractType": "life"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I need to get all the **id's** as array where displayName is **Accepted** which needs to be passed to next threadGroup

I have tried some jsonpath expression. But, Couldn't figure out the expression.

How do I get this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query will do the trick for you:

```
$..state.data[?(@.Contract.Status.displayName == 'Accepted')].linearId.id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri . It worked. I have another doubt... i need to iterate above response id list parallely with multi thread and request another http with that id. how to do it? i know we can use forloop controller. But not sure whether that will run with multi threads